# Elasticsearch simoultaneous sort

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple es indices - each of the tables from the database is kept in separate one.
Each of those indices has different mapping, although they present similar data. And so for dates I have:

- In index1 - **First_date** which is datetype (2018-05-22).
- In index2 - **First_date** which is integer (2018)
- In index3 - **justDate** - integer (2017)
- In index4 - **date** - string ("May 2018")

Is there way of sorting by all of these field simultaneously? I guess the answer might be script sorting, however I'm interested if this can be achieved in any other way.
If not, maybe at least same can be done for fields with same field type.

Answer (score 1):

It could've look like this:

```
POST index1,index2,index3,index4/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {"First_date": {"order": "desc"}},
    {"justDate": {"order": "desc"}},
    {"date": {"order": "desc"}}
  ]
}
```

But I assume you want to sort by all of the fields in date order which this query will not give you.

Solving this task with a script will bring unnecessary calculations on query time.

I would suggest you to create date-format field in each index and fill it on index time. In this case query above will work as is.